# Handle custom sign in (username/password) along with single sign in api's (google, apple etc.)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, single-sign-on, google-signin, spring-webflux

I am trying to setup my backend Spring Boot WebFlux REST API that client mobile apps will connect to and I am not sure how you handle both custom login such as an account created through my application and using a single sign in API like `Google Sign In` or `Sign In With Apple`

With my custom sign in I would generate a JWT that gets passed back to the client and then the client would send that in the `Authorization` header for each request and in my `ServerSecurityContextRepository` on the Spring API I would validate the JWT then set the security context.

With the single sign in API's they wouldn't have the JWT. The google signin [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) say to pass the token via a post request to your server to validate the token so I do that with a specific endpoint in my controller

```
val verifier = GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),JacksonFactory())
            .setAudience(listOf(""))
            .build()

val idToken: GoogleIdToken? = verifier.verify(loginData.authToken)
```

What is the recommended way to handle both scenarios or even authenticating between multiple single sign in apis? Do I just return a JWT for the single sign in api like I would with my custom one or is there a way that I can use my `ServerSecurityContextRepository` to handle everything removing the need for the specific endpoints for the single sign in apis?

*Disclaimer this is my first time implementing my own REST API with security

Comment: can you please post the relevant documentation for google sign in, and apple sign in that you refer to.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Google docs link added, I didn't look at the apple sign in docs yet because I am just trying to focus on one at a time but I an eventually going to be integrating that

Comment: you can start by looking into springs security and their premade google implementation https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2login-sample-boot